# Volley parseNetworkResponse is not called if last response body is null

Tags: android, android-volley

**Problem:**

Once I execute `DELETE` request using Volley, the very next request always goes to `onErrorResponse` block (bypassing `parseNetworkResponse`). After that all requests work fine until again I execute `DELETE` request. **The very next request doesn't work. If I try the same request again, it will work.**

**Description**:

I'm using `JsonObjectRequest` to fire all APIs. As for `DELETE` request, response body is `null`. Thus, `JsonObjectRequest` can't handle it and results into Parse error. So, I implemented `parseNetworkResponse` to explicitly check for `null` body. Now, `DELETE` request works. 
Here is my code,

```
@Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, PROTOCOL_CHARSET));
            //Allow null
            if (jsonString == null || jsonString.length() == 0) {
                jsonString = "{'status':'success'}";
            }

            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
```

Above snippet allowed `JsonObjectRequest` to handle null body. Now, `DELETE` request is working fine.

> But as soon as I fire `DELETE` request, **the very next request stops
>   working**. It directly goes to `onErrorResponse` and
>   `parseNetworkResponse` is not being called.

**Example:**

- Fired multiple POST, GET combinations. All good.
- Fired DELETE request. Successfully completed
- Fired one POST or GET request. Directly goes to onErrorResponse (bypassing parseNetworkResponse).
- Again tried the same request, it worked.
- Everything works properly until again I fire DELETE request. Once I fire DELETE request, then the very next request only doesn't work.

It throws below error,

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//MY_DOMAIN_NAME/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1484813989'><script type='text/javascript' src='//MY_DOMAIN_NAME/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1483605979'></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

I also tried to disable the cache for all requests. I even tried appending random number as a parameter to make sure url is always unique. Still it didn't work.

**Edit:**
Also further debugging shows that, `parseNetworkError` is called. Apache log on backend suggests that sometimes that faulty request reaches to the server and server returned correct response though it doesn't go to `parseNetworkResponse` and shows error. 
**Majority of the times, request doesn't even reach to the server at all.**

It sounds very weird bug. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: If not Volley it could be the server implementation.

Comment: If it reaches the server then parseNetworkResponse should also be called. It directly goes to onErrorResponse. What could be the server issue?

Comment: Try overriding `parseNetworkError` also or set breakpoints on your server-side application then debug

Comment: @BNK Yes it goes to parseNetworkError. In majority of the cases, that faulty request doesn't reach to server and it directly goes to parseNetworkError. I doubled check my device, it is properly connected to internet

Comment: Please provide with your full error content, I mean from the `com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line...`

Comment: VolleyError object contains this message: "com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//MY_DOMAIN_NAME/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1484813989'><script type='text/javascript' src='//MY_DOMAIN_NAME/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1483605979'></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>"

Comment: I  think that is the response from the web server, look like an HTML page

Comment: I get the same response when Volley doesn't even reach server and throws this error. Probably Volley is fetching it from cache.

Comment: This error Comes if server respond with error in HTML/XML format